# In Terraform is it possible to store multiple values in a single ssm_parameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-ssm

I'm wanting a single ssm_parameter to have multiple values.

```
values = dog, cat, turtle
```

I've tried doing

```
variable "dog" {
default = dog
}

variable "cat" {
default = cat
}

variable "turtle" {
default = turtle
}
```

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "animals" {
for_each {
"/default/animals" = "${var.dog}"
"/default/animals" = "${var.cat}"
"/default/animals" = "${var.turtle}"

name = each.key
type = "string"
value = each.value
}
```

When I check on in the parameter store the ssm path name "default/animals" is only populated by 1 value and not 3 values.

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching this in a wrong way. To make this work, you have to adjust the variable:

```
variable "animals" {
  type = list(string)
  description = "List of values for animals."

  default = ["dog", "cat", "turtle"]
}
```

Then, in the second step, you would have to adjust the resource:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "animals" {
  for_each = toset(var.animals)
  name = "/default/animals/${each.value}"
  type = "String"
  value = each.value
}
```

Make sure you understand first how `for_each` [1] works and as well how to convert a list to a set using `toset` built-in function [2].

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each

[2] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/toset

Comment: How would I go about it if I had an env-var file with

export TF_VARS_animal = "dog"
export TF_VARS_color = "blue"

with their values injected into a variables.tf

variable "animal" {}
variable "color" {}

How would I go about using those two variables and adding it into one ssm_parameter value?

Comment: You would have to create multiple occurrences of the same resource, but as far as I understood you, that is not the original question.